# Add RSS feeds to my Facebook

Tags: rss, facebook, rss-reader

I'd like to be able to add to my Facebook some of the blogs I follow, or, in other words, I want to use Facebook as RSS reader. It is possible to do such think?

The feature I'm interested in is only to read, not to distribute content. Just read RSS on my Facebook, getting updates from the blogs I follow on the wall.

Answer (score 1):

You could build "recipes" on [IFTTT](http://www.ifttt.com) linking [Feed channels](https://ifttt.com/feed) (RSS feeds from the blogs you want to follow) to your Facebook account with the [Facebook channel](https://ifttt.com/facebook).

Otherwise, you could also use [dlvr.it](http://dlvr.it)... !

Answer (score -1):

You most certainly can!

1. Navigate to "https://www.facebook.com/notifications"
2. At the top, you'll see a couple options for how you can get your notifications, including RSS:
   [Facebook RSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbdVH.png)
3. Copy that link to your RSS reader of choice.

**EDIT:** It appears I misread your question - unfortunately, the only information I can provide is that you can get your Facebook notifications as an RSS feed, but not that you can use Facebook itself as an RSS reader. My apologies.